# Errors when using array_push -- "First argument should be an array"

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<?php

function foo($bar) 
{
    global $products; 

    //$products = array();

    $query = 'SELECT p_name FROM 0_products WHERE p_category IN (' . $bar . ')';
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        array_push($products, $row);
        echo 'name pushed, ';
    }
}

require('mysql_ipb_connect.php'); // connect to ipb mysql database

$products = array(); 
foo(5);

?>
```

When I run it I get the following output:

```
Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in /home/rgcpanel/public_html/category/category.php on line 14
name pushed,
Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in /home/rgcpanel/public_html/category/category.php on line 14
name pushed,
Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in /home/rgcpanel/public_html/category/category.php on line 14
name pushed,
```

If I uncomment "$products = array();" then the output is correct:

```
name pushed, name pushed, name pushed,
```

Why is this happening? I declare the $products array outside of a function (so it's global), and then specify it as being a global inside the function. Something is not right, but I'm not sure what that is?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Test that although $products is declared elsewhere, that it is actually an array.  `var_dump($products)`, and that you declared it outside the function at global scope, rather than in another function, and finally that you declared it _before_ calling `foo()`.

Comment: Michael, @CoryDee -- I didn't think of this until now, but the file this is in is actually being included from inside a function that's a part of the CMS I'm using, so while the $products is outside of a function in this file, it's actually being included into a function. Does that mean it's not considered as a global variable?

Comment: If it was defined in an include inside a function, it is _not_ global unless you first declare `global $products` in the function, before it is initialized by the include.

Comment: I added that as an answer below...

Comment: what the hell is `global` doing in your code ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments, `$products` was initialized by an included file which was included inside a function.  That defines its scope to the function, rather than globally.  So you'll need to use `global $products;` before calling the include.

```
function func_that_defined_products() {
  global $products;
  include('file_that_defines_products.php');
}

// Now when called globally later, it will be at the correct scope.


function foo($bar) 
{
    global $products; 
    $query = 'SELECT p_name FROM 0_products WHERE p_category IN (' . $bar . ')';
    // etc...
}
```

In any case, I find it a little more readable to use `$GLOBALS['products']` instead of the `global` keyword.  And as always, wherever possible it is a preferred practice to pass the variable into a function rather than accessing it globally.

```
// If you can, do it this way
function foo($bar, $products) {
  // $products was a param, and so global is unnecessary
}
```

However in your case, if the CMS defines it you may lose the flexibility to do it that way...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the global variable as an array. To PHP, that variable is just null, which is NOT AN ARRAY.

Comment: "$products = array();" isn't initializing $products as an array?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize variables before using them. Code like yours will result in side effects (working fine if there is a database result; failing if its empty).

Another point:
Why don't you return the result instead of using the global operator? This is really bad style.

Next one:
When creating SQL statements: escape your variables!

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment this part

> //$products = array();

Initialise the `$products` as an array