# Global not working / How to sort by property value

Tags: php, function, sorting, callback, global

Could anyone explain why `$property` is `'name'` outside of the function and `null` inside? I've checked with `var_dump`, and I can't figure out why this isn't working. Isn't the global keyword there supposed to bring it inside?

```
$property = $_GET['property']; // 'name'
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    global $property;
    return strnatcmp($a->$property, $b->$property);
}
usort($files, 'cmp');
```

Alternatively, do you have a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this question: [Errors when using array_push -- "First argument should be an array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827909/errors-when-using-array-push-first-argument-should-be-an-array)

If the provided piece of code is called within another function (or a file included through another function), then $property isn't global, and thus cannot be retrieved through

```
global $property;
```

You could always do something simpler, since $_GET is already global.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $property = $_GET['property'];
    return strnatcmp($a->property , $b->$property);
}
usort($files, 'cmp');
```